# Will users using a pirated app get updates?

Tags: android

I am planning to launch my paid app to Android market and while researching I found that probably there is nothing that can stop the piracy of your paid app, period.

Of course I will be using Google's LVL, obfuscation etc., but still the app can be easily cracked. So I have convinced myself to live with this piracy.

Now my question is: Say today I launch the app with x content and the app is pirated. After 15 days I am adding more content to it. Will the pirated apps get the updates? I am planning to add more content every 2 - 4 weeks; will that help? I just want to ensure that only legit apps (who paid money to buy my app) gets the updates and not the pirated ones. I am OK if they pirate they newer version as well, because I will be launching newer versions often.

Comment: This might be better answered/documented here instead : http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

When you publish through Google Play, only paid users who have not had their purchase refunded *and* have installed the app through Google Play will receive your updates automatically.

If someone downloads a cracked apk and side loads it, they will not receive updates from Google Play for your app.

Answer (score 0):

What Raghav forgets is that the *distributor* of the cracked app **will** receive updates, which then get passed on for others to apply in turn.

Best advice? Focus less on chasing your tail in an attempt to beat the pirates and instead look balancing price and features. Keep the price right and be responsive to your customers and the app will produce a far better return